# How can I match response X or Y?

Tags: karate

I wanted to match my response is equal to X or Y. I saw many json specified samples but I couldn't utilize those samples. I have a string that I gathered from response and I want to match it with X or Y. It should be ok if it is equal to X or Y.

My reference language value that I defined above of the code = profile_language The language value that I defined from json response = response_content_language And match response_content_language contains ('en',profile_language)

Language value should be profile_language or if it is not then it should be value as 'en'.

And match response_content_language contains ('en',profile_language)

I took error as I expected.
[image: error]

Comment: I accepted previous question. Thank you. Could you please help about this question?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
* def table = [ "en", #(profile_language) ]
And match table contains response_content_language
```